Short movie where Santa Claus was an evil conqueror
I am looking for a comedic short movie done in the style of black-and-white news reels in which Santa Claus is an aggressor who tries to take over the world. He fails in the end, and has to make significant concessions to the Allied countries that fought him - and he might even end up in prison.
This movie would have been a "short" film that was used to introduce a feature length film (I forget the film) - but I don't think that the two went officially together. I think the movie I am looking for is animated. It is probably not more than 20 minutes. I recall it being in English, though it may have been subtitled.
Anyone know which short movie this is?

Year? Country\language? Animated or live-action? Where did you see it?

is it rare exports: a Christmas tale??? m not sure though

This movie would have been a "short" film that was used to introduce a feature length film (I forget the film) --- but I don't think that the two went officially together.  I think the movie I am looking for is animated.  It is probably not more than 20 minutes.  I recall it being in English, though it may have been subtitled.

Sounds like Bill Plympton's animated short Santa, the Fascist Years from 2008. From IMDb:

Funny spoof is so anti-Christmas that you'd probably want to watch this short before SILENT NIGHT, DEADLY NIGHT. In the film we learn about a secret time when Santa got greedy and tried to take over the world, which included a stint with Hitler. After this he decided to start a war with all the other holidays. Narrated by Matthew Modine, this short is told in a newsreel like fashion where it seems like the footage was taken from a secret FBI film.

Santa is eventually caught and tried. Here's a clip (it's not exactly B&W, but the colors are pretty drab):




That is the one!  Perfect!
